# What does the inscription on Wonder Woman's shield mean?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman-2017

Recently, I noticed that the DCEU's Wonder Woman's shield has some sort of inscription around the edges.

[image: shield]
 <sub>*Click image to enlarge*</sub>

From the best image that I could find, these inscriptions look like Greek to me.

[image: close-up on the shield's inscription]
 <sub>*Click image to enlarge*</sub>

So, what does this inscription mean?

Comment: As I remember, the shield in BvS/JL and WW aren't the same in appearance..

Comment: @Valorum as you said, it could be gibberish. I don't speak Greek and still, it looks like some random characters etched on the shield

Comment: great way to get the fans into overthinking :P

Comment: The shield in Wonder Woman has no visible inscription.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### What it *says*

Dr. Vincent Tomasso, Asst. Professor of Classics at Trinity College, Hartford, has kindly [transliterated](https://web.archive.org/web/20160509043719/http://nerdist.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Wonder-Womans-Greek-in-BvS.pdf) the text on the shield into Greek text (or rather the closest available letters in variants of Ancient Greek).

> The inscription reads (from [upper left-hand side, reading left to right](https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/57e72a0bbebafba4112843c5/1474819416169-331ZQU1JDEVYLKQAYLVC/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kCPztTQZpDiZMOuuCfUxiyx7gQa3H78H3Y0txjaiv_0fDoOvxcdMmMKkDsyUqMSsMWxHk725yiiHCCLfrh8O1z5QPOohDIaIeljMHgDF5CVlOqpeNLcJ80NK65_fV7S1UYlQ-m0oNUh_9buvyC-f1CSdhG_dNlqULB2ZTz-ses64A-QPhXXvNcU0N8wN7BGx0g/image-asset.jpeg?format=2500w))
>
> AΛΡΙFΑΛΨFΑΛΑ ΘΣΑΗΣΑΔΑΤΙΚΑ ΗΣΑΖΟΘΡΑΣΑ ΡΑΤΙΨFΑΗΑΣΑΤΙ ↑ΥFΑΝΑΜΡΑΜΑΝ ΤΑΜ↑UFΑΝΑΜΛ ΑΤΙΥFΛΗΣΑΤΙ ΑΤΗΘΑΒΑΛΑΝΤ
>
> ...
>
> **In ancient Greek, which is what Nerdist wanted me to translate, they’re meaningless.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Post #24: It’s All Greek to Her: the Inscriptions on Wonder Woman’s Equipment in ‘Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice’](http://www.rebootthepast.net/home/2016/9/25/post-24-its-all-greek-to-her-the-inscriptions-on-wonder-womans-equipment-in-batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice)</sup></sub>

### What it *means*

The text derives largely from Ancient Greek.

> The variant on WW’s sword appears in inscriptions from Attica and Argos in mainland Greece to the islands of Naxos and Ceos.

but with some odd additional letters that seem to be closer to runic script and some other crap just thrown in.

The inscription on the sword (in similar text) reads

> Line 1: ↑ΥFΑΝΑΜΡ ΑΜΑΝΤΑΙΝΑΜΡ ΑΜΑΝΙΑΜ↑ΥFΑ∀AΜΛΑ ΤΙΨΡΑHΑΣ
> Line 2: ΑΤΙΑΤΙΙΘΑΡΑΛΑΝΨΑΤΙΙΘΑΡΑNΨΑ ΛΡΙΕΑΓΨΕΑΡΑΘΣΑΗΣ
> Line 3: ΑΔΑΤΙΚΑ ΗΣΑΖΑOΘΡΑΣΑΛΑΤΙΨ HΑΗΑΣΑΤII)

is [supposedly](https://www.businessinsider.com/batman-v-superman-director-inspired-by-joseph-campbell-references-2016-3?r=US&IR=T) part of a quote from Joseph Cambell's *[Goddesses: Mysteries of the Feminine Divine](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17707946-goddesses)*

> “Originally Artemis herself was a deer, and she is the goddess who kills deer; the two are dual aspects of the same being. **Life is killing life all the time, and so the goddess kills herself in the sacrifice of her own animal.** Each life is its own death, and he who kills you is somehow a messenger of destiny that was yours from the start.”

Comment: What you write as an arrow ‘↑’ is something I thought was the runic letter ‘ᛏ’, [RUNIC LETTER TIWAZ TIR TYR T](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/16cf/index.htm).